# Highchart threshold issue

Tags: highcharts

Highchart(high stock graph) does not display graph line on first load with 
default range selector. It displays data only when user click on all.

```
Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
  credits: {
    enabled: false
  },
  chart: {
    height: 500
  },
  navigator: {
    xAxis: {
      labels: {
        style: {
          color: '#000'
        }
      }
    },
  },
  rangeSelector: {
    selected: 1
  },
  yAxis: {
    labels: {
      formatter: function() {
        return (this.value > 0 ? ' + ' : '') + this.value.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',');
      }
    },
    plotLines: [{
      value: 0,
      width: 2,
      color: 'silver'
    }]
  },
  tooltip: {
    pointFormat: '{point.tooltip}',
    valueDecimals: 2,
    split: true
  },
  title: {
    text: ''
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      stacking: 'stacked',
      turboThreshold: 10000
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'NILESH Benefits1 Plan',
    id: 'NILESH Benefits1 Plan',
    type: 'line',
    showInNavigator: true,
    color: '',
    data: ([{
      x: Date.UTC(2015, 9, 8),
      y: 17391107.275888,
      tooltip: 'NILESH Benefits1 Plan £17,391,107'
    },... (lengthy data deleted)
```

Fiddle    http://jsfiddle.net/nileshrokade/ks1pyj45/4/

Comment: Hello! Can you provide more information about your problem? What are you trying to achieve, error messages you are receiving, etc.

Comment: Please also create a [mcve] and insert the code to your post directly, not just outside SO. Use SO snippet to show how your code works, like jsFiddle does

Comment: There was working example in the fiddle with minimum code but anyways issue is related to known bug https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/9077

Answer (score 0):

It's because you've set the `rangeSelector.selected` equal to 1 (that means the button with index `1` will be pushed since the beginning). Please change that value to `5` (equivalent of the `All` button). Then it should be as you need.

```
rangeSelector: {
  selected: 5
}
```

**Live example:** http://jsfiddle.net/p8k4j3y7/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/rangeSelector.selected

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your reply and contributions . I have received reply from Highchart support and this was happening because of following  bug

https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/9077

And solution is to set

set dataGrouping.forced true